# How Do I Show All Products From All Categories Which Have a Certain Attribute = a Certain Value?

Tags: magento

So basically my Magento store sells t-shirts (not really) in a bunch of different categories. All t-shirts, regardless of category, have the *color* attribute = to either red, blue, green, etc.

I want to be able to link to a page for *blue* products, or *red* products, etc, and show them all regardless of parent category.

Thoughts? Thanks. I'm really not trying to add them all to another category manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the [Yoast's Landing Pages extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Yoast/extension/1915/yoast-landing-pages) a try. As explained in their [blog](http://yoast.com/landing-pages-module-magento/), you'll be able to create CMS pages that contains products listings filtered by any attribute you have created.
For example, to list all black products, you'd use something like (here the value "black" has id of 24):

```
{{block type="Yoast_Filter/Result" 
    name="filter_result" 
    template="catalog/product/list.phtml"  
    attribute_name="color" 
    value="24" }}
```

And as it is a CMS page, you'll also can customize the url to have something like: `http:/www.yourdomain.com/all-black-products.html`.
The description in magentoconnect says it's only compatible with 1.4, but I'm using with a 1.5, I can't remember if I had to change the code or not though.
HTH

Comment: Thanks - it needs some tweaking but it's definitely the way to go here. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

link them all to specific category and use navigation filters

Answer (score 0):

You can filter products by attribute value.. simply by using **addAttributeToFilter**

```
$attributeValue = 'red';
$attributeCode = 'color';

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, $attributeValue);
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.